# На изменение value повесить .change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Смотрите, есть такой код

```
$( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
            range: "max",
            min: 1,
            max: 1000,
            value: 1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );} 
        });
```

Как я понимаю в данном объекте изменяется свойство `value`, подскажите, а как мне повесить `change` на значение `value`?

PS никто не встречал информацию, как в [этом плагине](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemax)  изменить `label` на `input`, что бы после введения значения в инпут `slider` тоже двигался?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В документации все есть:

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "slidechange", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change

Comment: спасибо, ещё учусь и не научился продуктивно работать с документацией